# Strange behavior opening items from view after upgrade SP1 2010

Tags: upgrade, dialog-framework, modal-dialog

After installation of SP1 for SP2010, the items in libraries no longer displayed in a dialog. On the list is indicated that the items should be displayed in a dialog. 
After research I found out when a new view is created on the list the items reappear in a dialogue open when the new view is used.

**The problem only appears when i use de Edit (link to edit item) column.**
When using the ribbon all works fine.

Does anyone have a clue why this happens and how to solve this?

A solution I came up was to use PowerShell to clone alle views and delete the original views, but someone might know a cleaner/better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are the **AJAX options** of de List View WebPart. By disabling these options the action will work again. This bug is already sent to microsoft.

How can it be reproduced?
 - Create a new site collection.
 - Add a new document library to the site collection. Make sure the library opens its screens in dialog mode using advanced settings.
 - Change the default view, add the edit button in the view.
 - Change the list view webpart setting to enable the Enable Asynchronous Update and Show Manual Refresh Button in the AJAX options sections.
 - Upload a document and fill out the missing metadata.
 - Edit the document using the edit button on row level. Please note
 - Make your changes and press save.
 - The document will now open in full screen after pressing save.

What are the workarounds found?
 - When the library is set to open in full screen mode instead of the
   dialog, the issue is not happening.
 - Only use chevron and ribbon, when editing a document.
 - Disable AJAX options.